# Raspberry Pi 3 model B CentOS desktop installation

Tags: vnc

I have installed CentOS 7 on my Pi 3 using [CentOS-Userland-7-armv7hl-Minimal-1602-RaspberryPi3.img.xz](http://buildlogs.centos.org/centos/7/isos/armhfp/CentOS-Userland-7-armv7hl-Minimal-1602-RaspberryPi3.img.xz) 
 which got  me a minimal install.

I'm trying to get vncserver running on the Pi with a Desktop environment (any DE is fine)   but `yum groupinstall "Gnome Desktop"` does not have any packages to install.

Is there anyone who has done this already? Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to install Graphical on CentOS 7 on an Raspberry Pi 3, but it seems that some packages like GTK 2 are no ready yet, so its not possible to install KDE or even GNOME.

I spent a day trying this but without success.

I think we will have to wait a little until the problems are worked out.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change the repository as described in the net:

```
rm /etc/yum.repos.d/kernel.repo
yum reinstall centos-userland-release --disablerepo centos-kernel
```

The goal was to ensure that images were booting/working fine.
If you want to give it a try to extend the packages, you can add the following .repo file (unsigned packages!):

```
[c71611]
name=CentOS 7.3.1611 tmp repo
baseurl=http://armv7.dev.centos.org/repodir/c71611-pass-1/
enabled=1
gpgcheck
```

After this I was able to install tigervnc-server.
How to configure you can find in many places on the Internet.